# SKEmitterNode tied to a moving SKNode

Tags: sprite-kit, sknode, skemitternode

I am attempting to move a SKEmitterNode to follow a bullet in my game to give it a trailing effect however, no matter which way I attempt to implement this, it doesn't seem to work how I want it to and I'm at a loss for how to make this.

I have attempted to add the emitter to my main scene and manually moved the node a few times per second but it ends up not leaving a trail and keeping all the particles in one place like this:
[image]

Next I attempted to set the target node, however when I do this the trail goes for a bit then stops rather than following the bullet like it's supposed to. It also rotates and distorts from the rotation of the projectile like shown here:
[image]

For reference of the type of effect I'm looking for:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should populate the `targetNode` property of your emitter with a node that is not moving like the scene.

```
emitterNode.targetNode = self // where self is the current scene
```

Comment: YES! This is what I needed! You just completely solved my problem and I've been working on this for hours. Thank you so much!